# Ternary Operator in String

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I embedded a ternary operator in string as following:

```
return borderStyle.getThickness() + "|" + 
        borderStyle.getColor()!=null?ColorPersistor.asString(borderStyle.getColor()):"isnull" + "|" + 
                borderStyle.getLineStyle();
```

Surprisingly `ColorPersistor.asString(borderStyle.getColor())` was executed.

Why wasnt the call evaluated to "isnull" Isn't it possible to embed ternary operator in strings?

Comment: Well, apparently `borderStyle.getColor()!=null` evaluated to `true`. We cannot really tell what's happening, since your code snippet is not complete.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no - `borderStyle.getColor()` was never even *checked* to be not null - see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator has one of the **lowest** [Operator Precedeces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

That means: It is evaluated **after** the + operations in front of that.

So in fact you're *not* checking if `borderStyle.getColor()` is not `null` but you check that

`borderStyle.getThickness() + "|" + borderStyle.getColor()` is not null. Which is isn't as the literal String `"|"` is always `!= null`.

Whenever you use the ternary operator, be sure to use ( and ) to make sure you apply to the correct part of your equation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use parenthesis to ensure the operation precedence you intend (also, I highly recommend formatting it better, and breaking and indenting long lines for your own benefit of readability).

The way you wrote it, with default operator precedence, it evaluates like this:

```
 return 
  (borderStyle.getThickness() + "|" + borderStyle.getColor()) !=null ? 
         ColorPersistor.asString(borderStyle.getColor()): 
         ("isnull" + "|" + borderStyle.getLineStyle());
```

(because string `+` operator has higher precedence than the `?`). 
This is clearly not what you want.